# whose job it was

Tags: it-its-itself

> In ancient Rome, when a victorious general paraded through the streets, legend has it that he was sometimes trailed by a servant whose job ***it*** was to repeat to him, "Memento mori".

I found this sentence from 'Steve Jobs', Chapter 35, I wonder if the last "it" is unnecessary here. Why it is used here? Is it possible just a typo or any mistake?

Comment: It's **not** unnecessary, though the sentence makes sense with and without the *it*.

Comment: No, it's not a typo or a mistake, but two different constructions. The difference is that the expression "... it was a servant's job to repeat to him ..." is a cleft construction, and "... a servant's job was to repeat to him ..." is its non-cleft equivalent. The effect is that in the cleft construction, "a servant's job " is foregrounded.

Answer (score 4):

We do not need "it" in

> The servant's job was to repeat to him, "Memento mori".

We do need "it" in

> It was the servant's job to repeat to him, "Memento mori".

So, whether we use "it" in the quoted statement depends on which of these two we are thinking of when we write it.

Comment: Nicely explained. I pick up a difference in meaning between the two; 'It was X's job to ...' mirrors 'It was X's responsibility to', implying it wasn't X's full-time occupation.

Comment: Grammatically, the two are basically opposite constructions. The first has _the servant’s job_ is the subject and _to repeat…_ is the predicate. In the second, it’s the reverse: the subject is _to repeat…_ and _the servant’s job_ is the predicate. The subject has been [_it_-extrapositioned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraposition) and thus appears towards the end of the sentence.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the OP's original "it" sentence. "Whose" is a relative pronoun, which is said to be the possessive case for "who" or "which", but instead of being followed by a clause it's followed by a noun, that is the thing belonging to or of the "who" or "which", and then a clause. Eg., "The person whose job (noun) pays a lot of money." I can understand "The person whose job it was", ie., "It was the/a job of the person", but "The person whose job it was to collect money" ends up being "It was to collect the money the/a job of the person."  Is that grammatical?

Comment: @Zebrafish In the OP's example "it was to repeat to him" is an _it_ cleft construction. The non-cleft version does not have the "it".

Comment: @Zebrafish "The person whose job it was to collect money" is perfectly  standard English as far as I'm concerned, as is the OP's example. "It was the job of [that person] to collect the money".

Comment: @Zebrafish: The two constructions are (1) Cleft: "... it was a servant's job to repeat to him ... ". (2) Non-cleft: "... a servant's job was to repeat to him ...". Recall the contrast between cleft and non-cleft as in "I bought a red wool sweater" (non-cleft) ~ "It was a red wool sweater that I bought" (_it_ cleft)

Comment: @GEdgar It would have helped if you'd explained in your answer that the second example is a cleft construction, while the first is its non-cleft equivalent. The foregrounding / backgrounding contrast would thencomplete the explanation.

Comment: Thank you all very much. This structure is explained very clear now.